# Oracle Home not recognized in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: oracle, jupyter-notebook

I am using a PySpark three notebook, and am testing out the functionality of `cx_oracle`. After installing the package, the oracle instant client, and point `ld_library_path` to the oracle libraries, I could import `cx_Oracle` cleanly on my local machine.

Once in the notebook, I added the `ld_library_path` and `Oracle_home` variables to the jupyter environment but found new errors:

> DatabaseError: DPI-1005: unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Is there a best practice for setting `oracle_home` in a Jupyter notebook?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't that mean it can't connect using the connection string you specified, rather than it can't find an environment variable? Have you tried to manually ping the DB server, and if that works, connect to the lister port (via telnet)? Maybe there's a firewall in the way or something.

Comment: DPI-1005 means OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed.  This is well before connection.  What Oracle libraries do you have on the machine?  It sounds like some mismatch somewhere.  I'd triple check the environment variables are set correctly.